# Mysqli not able to fetch info or bind_params

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, null, prepared-statement

so I'm not sure what's wrong here, I've tried doing this multiple ways, and I can't get it to work, I followed the  manual but it doesn't seem to change, i have  a simple login.php ,I've checked my query already but it works on mysql, i have error reporting on, what I suspect is that it might be because I'm testing this on WAMP server, but im not sure if that has anything to do please help.

EDITED

```
<?php
 session_start();
 ERROR_REPORTING( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
 ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(-1);
 include_once 'UniversalConnect.php';
 class login{

 public function __construct()
 {
 $this->dologin();
 }

 private function dologin()
 {
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","root","mrt");
 var_dump($mysqli);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE nombre_administrador= ? AND password= ?";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
 if ( !$stmt ) {
 printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error);
 die;
 }
 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$pass);
 if ( !$name ) {
 printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
 }
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 if($stmt->num_rows==1)
 {
 var_dump($rows);
 header("location: indexSCAF.html");
 else{
 $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
 $errflag = true;
 }
 if($errflag) {
 $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
 session_write_close();
 exit();
 }
 }

 }/*close function dologin*/
 }/*close class */
?>
```

the results of the var_dumps give

```
 string 'admin' (length=5)
 string 'test' (length=4)

 object(mysqli)[3]
 public 'affected_rows' => null
 public 'client_info' => null
 public 'client_version' => null
 public 'connect_errno' => null
 public 'connect_error' => null
 public 'errno' => null
 public 'error' => null
 public 'error_list' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'host_info' => null
 public 'info' => null
 public 'insert_id' => null
 public 'server_info' => null
 public 'server_version' => null
 public 'stat' => null
 public 'sqlstate' => null
 public 'protocol_version' => null
 public 'thread_id' => null
 public 'warning_count' => null

 object(mysqli_stmt)[4]
 public 'affected_rows' => null
 public 'insert_id' => null
 public 'num_rows' => null
 public 'param_count' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'errno' => null
 public 'error' => null
 public 'error_list' => null
 public 'sqlstate' => null
 public 'id' => null

object(mysqli_stmt)[4]
 public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
 public 'param_count' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'errno' => null
 public 'error' => null
 public 'error_list' => null
 public 'sqlstate' => null
 public 'id' => null

 null
```

Comment: Did you try enabling mysqli error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You don't have any error handling for your database calls. Add this to the top of your script to have mysqli throw exceptions: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. Apart from that you should not be storing plain-text passwords in your database. Instead you should salt and hash them.

Comment: Shouldn't `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$user,$pass);` be `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$pass);`? Seems to be the most logical explanation, as you don't have a `$user` variable.

Comment: yes, sorry, i just changed it, thank you , however it's still throwing all null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bind_result before fetching the result so that your prepare statement fetches correctly .

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","root","mrt");
$sql = " SELECT userId,userName From user WHERE nombre_administrador= ? AND password= ? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$user,$pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows>0)
 {
   $stmt->bind_result($userId,$userName)
  while($stmt->fetch())
   {
     // success handle result 
      header("location: indexSACF.html");
   }
 }
else
{
  $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
  $errflag = true;
}

$stmt->free_result()
$stmt->close();
```

**Note:** In query statement never use select * as it would not bind your results. instead use arameters

```
SELECT userId,userName  From user WHERE nombre_administrador= ? AND password= ? ;
```

For more info you can refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Your answer will fail. You're missing a crucial piece of code.

Comment: ...in other words, `WHERE`